# Vue doesn't render one of the components. No errors, even shows in DOM, looks evrything right for me

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components and one of them doesnt want to render. It even appears in DOM. I would think I messed up some paths and so on, but if it shows in DOM then evrything is alright. I dont event know what part of code to attach over here for you to view.. so will attach

[picture of a DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmvnC.png)

the beggining of my App.vue

```
       <template>
                    <div>
                    <field-modal></field-modal>
                    <form> // All below just renders fine
                            <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" :style="progressBar"></div>
                            </div>
                            <fileds-registration v-for="(field, i) in info">
                            </fileds-registration>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="!isButton">
                                    Send Data
                            </button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
            </template>
<script>
        import FiledsRegistration from './components/Action.vue';
        import FieldModal from './components/Modal.vue';
export default {
        components: {
                FiledsRegistration,
                FieldModal
        },
        data(){ .......
```

And my whole component Modal.vue file which doesnt want to render

```
<template>
        <div class="modal">
                <p>Here we go</p>
        </div>
</template>
<script>
        export default
        {
                components: {
                },
                data(){
                        return {

                        }
                }
        }
</script>
<style scoped>
        .modal
        {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                background: blue;
        }
<style>
```

Comment: did you check the computed styles?  maybe some inherited styles are collapsing it?  maybe font-size is too small?  I can see that the div itself is being selected (highlighted in grey)

Comment: Posting an answer to finalize.  It'd help if you posted what resolved it for you.  Possibly as your own answer.  You can post your own answer and accept it as a solution if you want.